# issue while connecting to local database for MVC3 + EF app

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to implementing an application on MVC3 + EntityFramework. Can somebody suggest as what approach to apply to access my tables and views from my existing local database (Sql server 2008). I could see some default files created under App_data folder which i dont want.

Cheers,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

You could change the connection string in your web.config to point to your real SQL database:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Hey Darin - I tried this option in the config file as well as assigning the name 'DefaultConnection' on the default constructor of my class in the model section of my application. But no luck.